# The tag 'forces' is quite specific, what should we do with it?

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [forces](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forces) seems to be very specific. It has at the moment 14 questions and no tag definition.

Is it too specific?

Could/should we do something about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest we make [forces](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forces) a tag synonym of [physics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) because...

- ... the concept of `forces` being a subset of `physics`
- ... half of the questions tagged with `forces` are also tagged with `physics`
- ... someone is rarely expert in `forces`, they're more often expert in `physics`.

This makes it more of a meta tag, in my humble opinion.

Comment: This has been done.